# python : ldap where clause

Tags: python, ldap

```
conn=ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap.server.com:389')
results=conn.search_s('ou=active,ou=infra,o=company', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'uid=bob')

results=[('uid=bob,ou=active,ou=infra,o=company', {'telephonenumber': [''], 'cn': ['Bob Bensen (bob)'], 'uidnumber': ['123'], 'manager': ['cn=Andy Home (ahome),ou=sector,ou=dept,o=company'])]

results[0][1]['manager']  ---> ['cn=Andy Home (ahome),ou=sector,ou=dept,o=company']
```

How to get the UID of all the users in 'ou=active,ou=infra,o=company' where manager's cn = ahome?

Comment: The LDAP where clause is called a filter, but you'd need to show some code for how you're obtaining those results for anyone to say anything helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Change the last part of this line, which is the filter from:

```
results = conn.search_s('ou=active,ou=infra,o=company', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'uid=bob')
```

To something like:

```
results = conn.search_s(
    'ou=active,ou=infra,o=company',
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    'manager=cn=Andy Home (ahome),ou=sector,ou=dept,o=company'
)
```

Note that the `manager` attribute stores the *full DN* of the manager object, so it's not enough to just specify `ahome`. You may need to look-up the DN first before doing the search (it should be the first item of each LDAP result).

Comment: i figured it out, I can do   results = conn.search_s(
    'ou=active,ou=infra,o=company',
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    'manager=cn=*ahome*,ou=sector,ou=dept,o=company'
)